# @click-append-inner not working in vuetify 3 code

Tags: vue.js, vuetifyjs3

I tried using '@click:append-inner="randomFunc"' to trigger a click event on the icon I appended internally in my 'v-text-field', but it did not work. Furthermore the cursor is not changing to a pointer on hover over the icon.

I tried based on the Vuetify.js3 documentation [icon event](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icon-events).

```html
         <v-text-field 
            variant="outlined" 
            density="compact" 
            append-inner-icon="mdi-plus-box"
            @click:append-inner="addSomething"
            >
         </v-text-field>
```

browser screen shot on:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works flawlessly when I put it into a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVUEtugzAQvcrIm7RKDa3SRYVI1arHKF04xkhW8Uf2gBIh7p4xkEBW9rx5n9H7HVgMMv/2Pus7xQpWojK+Fag+KwtQ9lx4P32nQTqLQlsVFmgCUZ2RN1q19Q0E6EXQwuKxYq7DlhR1xdZtrWzUeKGtdMYLidslBSpbc20phmtKJJqpNfdtF/nJnbfcL9lq+V9sJcS2nTmp4JqftIz7/apYz863d9/hWQmugck4FjAMj27juJRBBo9tJGQuq8w3JdIYZdAeISrs5i618S4gDBBUAyM0wRnYUf+7RAcg34jLLbdcOCby0+tzsp8NyYqNL+yQHbIPlt737I39XQF6LJaE)